# How to split two elements from a single array?

Tags: python

How to separate this two elements from a single array?

```
[array([0.1, 5.6])] # numpy array

target:

[array([0.1]), array([5.6])]
```

Comment: Is this an array from the python `array` module or an `np.array` ?

Comment: paste your code what you have tried?

Comment: Would you have always have exactly 2 elements inside `array` or there might be more elements? If last what should happen in such situation?

Comment: It's not exactly as two elements always, any idea on this numpy array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```py
map(lambda x: [x], your_array)
```

Example:

```py
source = ["a", "b", "c"]
target = map(lambda x: [x], source)

print(list(target))
# OUTPUT:
# [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would appreciate if you elaborate your goal.
Coming to your question,you could easily do similar to the following using numpy.

import numpy as np

list_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

array = np.array(list_data)

new_array = np.array(array[:x], array[x:])
where x is a position.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) for some reasons instead of the [build-in lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), you should do this:

```
from array import array
arr = [array('d', [0.1, 5.6])]
spl = [array('d', a) for a in arr]
```

However, I would recommend a simple list for your task:

```
lis = [0.1, 5.6]
sp = [[dbl] for dbl in lis]
```

Then you do not need to import a module.